# Selenium WebDriver doesn't open URL completely

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working with Selenium WebDriver in JAVA, and I am trying to open a URL from a Sports betting site, similar to this one:

https://www.randombetpage.com/en/live/event/?id=10491330

However, Selenium WebDriver opens this one:

https://www.randombetpage.com/en/live

I checked it and the URL works on my browser, the problem is the parameter ?id=......

Any idea of how to solve this? I want to get the full HTML document to scrape it later with Jsoup.

Comment: urls are not working

Comment: it solved by itself! I was doing something wrong or something.  URLs were an example

Answer (score 0):

If "https://www.randombetpage.com/en/live/event/?id=10491330" if it requires authentication (i.e if this page only visible post login) then first automate login flow then try to open it.